# Opencart Extensions issue

Tags: opencart2.x, opencart-module

So I have just cleaned installed Opencart 2.2.0.1b from Github but i'm having one quite big issue with it.

If I click onto Extensions it only shows -
Extension Installer
Extensions
Modifications
Events

If I click onto Extensions and choose modules (or shipping analytics ect) from the drop down and press install it takes me to a inner page with a message saying "Permission Denied!".

Iv'e tried so far, creating a new admin, setting all permissions (from access permission) adding my ip to the api, adding vqmod, creating a new api, updating, manually adding all permissions to the database (was only a rough copy though and it did cause a few errors) and I think that maybe it.

If anyone can help it will be gratefull.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving permissions to apache?
Is all of your folders are 0755 and files 0644?